# bootstrap multiselect when reloading page in ajax Intermittent

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-select

I'm loading a page in ajax containing a form with a bootstrap multiselect. In my ajax complete, I reload the page in ajax to apply changes. Once this is done, the multiselect doesn't work anymore. Whenever I click it it doesn't expand (there is no js error). If I submit the form again, it works fine. Actually it works exactly half the time, if it doesn't expand, next time I refresh the page via ajax (from anywhere, not only submit) it will work.

So far I tried to rebuild and destroy it before rebinding but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
<select multiple name="showhide" id="showhide_select">
     <option value="uid">uid</option>
     <option value="name">name</option>
     <option value="age">age</option>
</select>

<script>
    $("#showhide_select").multiselect({
        buttonText: function(options, select) {
            if (options.length === 0) {
                return 'Select columns to hide';
            }
            else{
                return options.length + ' columns hidden';
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

edit : 
bootstrap 3.3.6, jquery 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are initializing your multiselect in a page-related event like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
});
```

If so, then you need to call your initializing script again when the ajax request is done

Comment: It's  being initialized, I can see all the html and css added in the inspector. But it's only clickable one in two times. Even if I initialise it in the document.ready. When I can't expand it and I click on the select : "aria-expanded" stays false and  "open" class is never added to the  parent <div> for some reason.